# How to display all data name list form my database into a popup

Tags: database, popup

This is the part where I shoul get all data from a certain and initialize it

```
$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT firstname, lastname FROM mampirao');
while($row = $stmt->fetch_array()) {
$tag_name = $row['firstname'];
$tag_lname = $row['lastname'];

}
```

and this the part inside a script I want to appear all data in a popup

```
  var myIcon4 = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'img/calawit.png',
  iconAnchor: [2, 24]});
L.marker([13.6653787, 123.5301075], {icon: myIcon4}).addTo(map);
var initialContent = (' <h3>Mampirao</h3><p style="font-size: 20px;">List of Farmer <br> </p> <p><a href="#"> Open in new Window </a></p>  <?php echo "$tag_name"?> <?php echo "$tag_lname"?>
    <br><br><div><image style="width:100%"src="img/picture1.png "alt="image"/></div>')
```

but in my popup it only show record, How can I make all the data appear to my popup?

and another thing is I want to put another popup inside that pupop, can someone help for this?

Comment: you need a loop over the array to generate the html

Comment: Can you please help how to put loop on it

Comment: you need to hire a consultant if you don't know how to put a loop into code.